# Java gui and constructor

Tags: java, user-interface, constructor, awt, frame

I have a doubt regarding java and gui which has been pestering me for a while now.Below i have posted a small code and I need you to have a look at its constructor part.

```
import java.awt.*;  

class First extends Frame {  

    First(){
        Button b=new Button("click me");  
        b.setBounds(30,100,80,30);// setting button position
        add(b);//adding button into frame  
        setSize(300,300);//frame size 300 width and 300 height  
        setLayout(null);//no layout manager  
        setVisible(true);//now frame will be visible, by default not visible  
    }  

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        First f=new First();  
    }
}
```

I understand that in the main method, we have created an object of the class "First". I also understand that when a new object is created, the constructor of its class is called for initialization purposes.

My doubt is that how are we using setSize, setLayout, setVisible functions without the dot operator? If these functions are to modify the objects, the creation of which triggers the constructor call, still, shouldn't we be using the this pointer? Isn't that how we do it all the time? But I have come across similar pieces of code all over the internet and have been really confused lately. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: It's implied, of course if you want to use "this" you can, but you're just adding more typing and, as lots of people who haven't used ObjectiveC, complain about, Java is quite verbose.  Also, don't use null layouts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setSize`, `setLayout`, and `setVisible` methods can be used directly, because they are members of the `Frame` class, and your `First`class is a subclass of `Frame`.

In that sense, you are working "inside" the `Frame` object so can call its members directly.

You only need to qualify method calls from outside an object, so that Java can tell which object you are calling.

It's possible to call these methods explicitly, using `this`, i.e.
    `this.setSize()`, but the `this` is assumed, so you can write more concise code. Not all languages do this - for example in Python you always need to specify the `this` (which is called `self` in Python)

Comment: hey DNA,just one more small doubt.When we create an object of "First" class,the constructor of the base class gets called which means that the frame() constructor gets called and a frame is created.Then,the derieved class constructor gets called,which further calls setSize and other functions to modify this frame.Is that what happens?Please correct me if i am wrong.I am a beginner and want to get my basics right :)

Comment: Yes, that's right - I suggest you try it out by creating your own class and subclass and printing something out in the constructors so you can see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you posted contains references to methods such as setSize(), setLayout() which are inherited from Frame class and are always available with currently executing object.

In java there is no concept of explicit pointers as in C or C++. But there is `this` keyword that refers to current object.

Use of this keyword is optional as thus,

```
setSize(300,300);

this.setSize(300,300);
```

both mean one and the same thing.